# Inserting 2 values to MySql from a single selection tag of drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to insert 2 values to Mysql from a single selection of drop down menu?

The example of mysql syntax for inserting the form values is as following:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO menu (food, image_extension) VALUES (%s, %s)",
GetSQLValueString($_POST['food'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['image_extension'], "text"),

mysql_select_db($database_menu, $menu);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $menu) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "menu.php?status=choosen";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

I'm trying to insert values of 2 columns (food & image_extension) from each selected tag of the following dropdown list to MySql but it can't insert data to image_extension column. It only update food column.

```
<select name="food, image extension" class="dropdownmenu" input id="food" value="<?php echo $_POST['food'].$_POST['image_extension']; ?>"> 
<option value="selected="selected">Select Food</option>
<option value="Pizza, pizza.jpg">Pizza</option>
<option value="French Fry' frenchfry.jpg">French Fry</option>
</select>
```

I'm confused about how to put values in the following three attributes of the above dropdown list properly in this case?

```
1. <select name="food, image extension" 
2. <select value="<?php echo $_POST['food'].$_POST['image_extension']; ?>" 
3. <option value="Pizza, pizza.jpg">Pizza</option>
```

Any guideline shall be gighly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two different names for the select just grab the value from the select menu and turn it into an array

```
<?php

$food = explode (",", $_POST['food']);

//$food[0] will equal Pizza, $food[1] will equal pizza.jpg
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO menu (food, image_extension) VALUES ({$food[0]}, {$food[1]})";

?>

<select name="food" class="dropdownmenu" id="food">
<option value="Pizza, pizza.jpg">Pizza</option>
<option value="French Fry, frenchfry.jpg">Pizza</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What should be the `<select name=` in this case? Should the variable `$food` contain both the column names `food` & `image_ extension` like `$food = "food, image_extension"` in this case?

Comment: No whenever you have <select name="food"> then whenever you pass this value through post the value will equal "pizza, pizza.jpg"  so then you will you the explode above to convert this into an array that you can insert into the database

Comment: Check out the new revision above

Comment: Now after submitting the form the database server is considering the option value `<option value="Pizza, pizza.jpg">Pizza</option>` as column name.  it gives the error `Unknown column 'Pizza' in 'field list` but here `Pizza` is the value of `food` column and `pizza.jpg` is the value of `image_extension` column. What I'm doing wrong here? Should I modify option value? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved anyway with the precise guideline of an expert fellow in www.phpbuilder.com I'm presenting the whole solved scenario below:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) { 

//("," Comma within the double quote shall be used as delimiter here) 
$food=explode(",",$_POST['food']); 
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO menu (food, image_extension) VALUES (%s, %s)", 

// The column names in the following string should be replaced by the newly created 
// array elements along with trim function to remove any unexpected white space.       

GetSQLValueString (trim($food[0]), "text"), 
GetSQLValueString (trim($food[1]), "text");

mysql_select_db($database_menu, $menu); 
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $menu) or die(mysql_error()); 

$insertGoTo = "menu.php?status=choosen"; 
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "" : "?"; 
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
} 
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo)); 
}
```

The html part should be changed to the following:

```
 <select name="food" class="dropdownmenu" input id="food" 
 value="<?php echo  $_POST['food']; ?>">
 <option value="selected="selected">Select Food</option>
 <option value="Pizza, pizza.jpg">Pizza</option>
 <option value="French Fry' frenchfry.jpg">French Fry</option>
 </select>
```